# update the data in json file using sencha store

Tags: json, extjs

I have store that reads the data from json file
and here's my store

```
  Ext.define(
  "CM.store.Customers",
{
  extend: "Ext.data.Store",
  model: "CM.model.Customer",
  idProperty: "id",
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSync: true,
  alias: 'store.customers',
  proxy: {
     type: "rest",
     url: "data/Customers.json",
     reader:
     {
        type: "json",
        rootProperty: "data",
        messageProperty: 'error'
     }
  }
});
```

When I put autoSync property true in the store 
and trying to make any actions on the store such delete or Add it said the file not found " I mean the json the file "
but the store gets the data from it in the first time and loads it

and here's my Json file

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": 1,
     "firstName": "Mahmoud",
     "lastName": "Zakal",
     "subscriptionDate": "3/1/2015",
     "accountType": 2,
     "active": true
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "firstName": "Peter",
     "lastName": "Strong",
     "subscriptionDate": "9/1/2015",
     "accountType": 1,
     "active": false
  }
  {
     "id": 3,
     "firstName": "Dani",
     "lastName": "Alice",
     "subscriptionDate": "11/10/2015",
     "accountType": 1,
     "active": true
  },
  {
     "id": 4,
     "firstName": "Hannah",
     "lastName": "Hester",
     "subscriptionDate": "11/17/2015",
     "accountType": 1,
     "active": true
  }
 ]
}
```

and this is the error i get in console when I try to make any action in the store

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>      The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or        is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: You added your code, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: sorry my question is i get error everytime trying to make change in the store like delete or add

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot update a file on the server without a server-side script or program.

You could use various back-end technologies, like PHP, Perl, JSP, C#, node.js, ... - whatever is supported by your server.

But you can't just write into a server file from the front-end - although there may be a loophole using `HTTP/1.1 PUT` method. But that also has to be supported by your server, and you would have to tell ExtJS to use `method:'PUT'` (default is `POST`).

Comment: so does it there any helpful resource about how to do that exactly in c#